# connection between nodejs api and swift app

Tags: node.js, swift, express, alamofire

i'm trying to create an api, which my ios app is connected to. However i keep getting prompt that `error: not found` when i run post request on and set the parameters to `id, name, birth and country`. however if i just run `url/users/14253/test/10-20-1992/denmark` in postman it works fine, so i'm a bit confused what i do wrong?

api route

```
router.post('/:id/:name/:birth/:country', function(req, res, next) {

  var params = req.params;

  var accessHeader = req.headers;


  var user = new User({
    _id: params.id,
    name: params.name,
    birthday: new Date(params.birth),
    country: params.country
  });

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    }
  });


});
```

swift alamofire request

```
func passUserData(id: String, name: String, birth: String, country: String, token: AccessToken) {

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("http://url/users", method: .post, parameters: ["id" : id, "name" : name, "birth" : birth, "country" : country], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { closureResponse in
        if String(describing: closureResponse.result) == "SUCCESS"
        {
            print(closureResponse)
        } else {
            print(closureResponse)

        }}
}
```

Comment: Could you print `params` in your node.js code?

Comment: You don't pass any params in the url, but in the body. The request you do on the client side has the following url : "/users" with the parameters in a body

Comment: Looks to me like the swift code will produce an url in the form of http://IP:3000/users?id=bla&name=bla&etc, absolutely not the url you want. The parameters need to be embedded into the url itself.

Comment: oh okay so instead of using params i should just add to url? in swift code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you pass the parameters in the url :

```
 Alamofire.request("http://172.20.10.2:3000/users/" + id + "/" + name + "/" + birth + "/" + country, ...);
```

Either you pass the parameters in the body :

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {

  var body = req.body;

  var accessHeader = req.headers;


  var user = new User({
    _id: body.id,
    name: body.name,
    birthday: new Date(body.birth),
    country: body.country
  });

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    }
  });


});
```